# Which browsers support the <embed> and <object> tags?

Tags: html, flash, xhtml, tags, standards

I am working on a department website that needs to be standards compliant (xhtml 1.0 transitional), but embedded flash keeps breaking the validation. We use the `<embed>` tag because we need to support most major browsers.

We can't use external tools, since the site is managed through a system and the admins don't like us putting extra tools (like JavaScript libraries etc) that could interfere with their template engine.

How widely supported is the object tag?  Is it safe to use only the `<object>` tag and remove the `<embed>` tag all together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<embed>` is invalid in XHTML 1.0 and HTML 4, but it’s [valid in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-embed-element.html#the-embed-element), so you could switch to the HTML5 doctype and be compliant with that standard instead.

As mentioned above, the [Flash Satay](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay/) article at A List Apart is a great explanation of how to get Flash working with just an `<object>` tag. It’s not so much which browsers support `<object>` (I think only Netscape 4 doesn’t), it’s more that the differences in *how* the browsers support Flash embedded with `<object>` screw everything up.

Definitely read the article. It’s got code you can use and everything. In short, `<object>` on its own works fine, unless you want a Flash movie to start playing before it’s fully downloaded. Then you need another Flash movie to act as a wrapper.

Comment: Is embed supported by all modern browsers? If so, it would seem that this would be the best solution by far. Only the W3C recommendation was the reason not to use embed.

Comment: @Django: I’m really not sure, you’ve got a good point though. There’s [an article on A List Apart from 2006](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/byebyeembed/) saying that IE doesn’t handle `<embed>` very gracefully when the user doesn’t have the right plug-in installed.

Comment: I think it's safe to say the Flash Satay article is quite outdated in the HTML5 era (2012). Cherouvim's suggestion of SWFObject should be marked as the most correct answer.

Comment: @Micros: I do see your point on the Flash Satay article being outdated. However, the question did explicitly ask about browser support for the `<object>` and `<embed>` tags, and said that they were looking to use Flash without relying on a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 6):

It's best if you use http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ which deals with browser compatibility issues.

[Google suggests using swfobject](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) as well.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>This validator: http://validifier.com/ does a pretty good job, and I've had decent results with it.</strike> (Edit note: site is now "adult" & presumably NSFW.)

There's also this article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay/ on how to embed without an embed tag, but I believe it involves using a container movie, which isn't much fun but does get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

The `<embed>` tag is not a valid tag. The `<object>` tag is. Cherouvim is correct in that swfobject will take care of all of that for you. I highly recommend it.

Comment: [`<embed>` is valid in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-embed-element.html#the-embed-element).

Answer (score 1):

The `<object>` tag helps for the browser who use ActiveX controls to display properly the flash movie and it is mainly used for IE . With newest  IE 7 and 8 the flash movie works without the `<object>` tag  and `<embed>` tag is for Netscape and related to it browsers using Netscape plugin to display a flash movie.

So it better to use both to be safe that your flash movie will have a good chance to be played on all the browser