# XSLT issues with playing Flash in IE and FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, xml, flash, xslt

Alright, I am trying to play a flash video in a YUI panel.  I was having trouble getting it to work in IE.  Fixed it, but then that caused it not to work in FireFox.  I have spent HOURS debugging and this is what I found: My XSLT doc is causing the problem! Here it is:

```
<div id="mediaDisplay">
  <xsl:if test="//video/videoFile">
    <div class="flash" id="flashVid">
      <noscript>
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/playerVar1.2.swf" width="525" height="425" id="MediaEmbedObject" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
          <param name="movie" value="flash/playerVar1.2.swf"/>
          <param name="salign" value="lt"/>
          <param name="loop" value="false"/>
          <param name="menu" value="false"/>
          <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
          <param name="AutoPlay" value="true"/>
          <param name="FlashVars" value="movieSrc={$videouri}"/>
          <embed AutoPlay="true" src="flash/playerVar1.2.swf" quality="high" name="videogalleryObject" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" width="525" height="425" id="videogalleryObject" FlashVars="{$videouri}" allowFullScreen="true">
          </embed>
        </object>
      </noscript>
      <form action="" name="flashForm">
        <fieldset>
          <input type="hidden" name="flashDivId" value="flashVid"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="flashWidth" value="525"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="flashHeight" value="425"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="flashUrl" value="flash/playerVar1.2.swf"/>
          <input id="playingFlash" type="hidden" name="FlashVars" value="{$videouri}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="flashName" value="Flash"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="flashAltText" value="{//video/altText}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
</div>
```

Now, the way it is written here it works in FireFox.  To make it work in IE the only thing that actually did the trick was removing the `data="flash/playerVar1.2.swf"` attribute from the `<object>` tag and and changing it to `value="flash/playerVar1.2.swf"`.  Doing this gets me full functionality in IE, but nothing in FireFox.  I'd give you a link to see for yourself but it is still in QA. Does anyone have a way of making this work on across all platforms.  Is there a way to run browser detection inline in my XSLT and then give it conditionals? Any and all ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond Andy. I should remember to check back here more often, but usually I end solving the problem before an answer is posted. I know I should come here and post my solution to my question, and I am going back to do that now.  I have been busier than ever and I, obviously, neglect coming back here. Plus, I have not had a single solution that worked, that I could accept as a viable solution. What do I do in that circumstance?

Comment: It is completely valid to answer your own question and doing so will help future users when they discover this question. It might also earn you reputation when others upvote your question and/or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing in browser detection and ran different code for IE than the rest where value="flash/playerVar1.2.swf" instead of data="flash/playerVar1.2.swf". Easiest way to satisfy the beast of IE in my opinion. Oh, this works fine in its original iteration in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that `<embed>` inside `<object>` is not valid markup. Even if it is, you should really look at [Which browsers support the <embed> and <object> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254027/which-browsers-support-the-embed-and-object-tags) since `<embed>` is *only* [valid in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-embed-element.html#the-embed-element).